# How to use nextval() to insert a row containing its own ID in a string

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, auto-increment, create-table

I have a table that contains a column with a string containing its own ID.
How can I insert a new line using a single SQL statement?

```
id| URL
--|----------------------
 1|"http://example.com/1"
 2|"http://example.com/2"
 3|"http://example.com/3"
```

I need something like

```sql
NEXT_ID = SELECT nextval('table_name_id_seq');
insert into table_name (id, name) values (NEXT_ID, 'http://example.com/' + NEXT_ID) returning *
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3NwLNBirN7mHKpDk9NyHSy/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to select the next serial in a subquery first:

```
insert into test(id, url)
select id, 'http://example.com/' || id::text
from (select nextval('test_id_seq') as id) x;
```

---

You could also use a computed column instead would make for cleaner insert code:

```
create table test(
  id SERIAL,
  url text,
  new_url text generated always as (url || id::text) stored
);

insert into test(url) values ('http://example.com/');
```

Gives you:

```
| id  | url                 | new_url              |
| --- | ------------------- | -------------------- |
| 1   | http://example.com/ | http://example.com/1 |
```

Comment: I can't add a computed column, because that table contains polymorphic data, so it wouldn't make sense for other records. :(

Comment: @Vitim.us: ok, so you want to use the first query in my answer.

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize it was 2 different approaches

Comment: you could also use a CTE and put the nextval call in the WITH clause; this is basically just a variation on @GMB's original suggestion of putting it in the from, so just mentioning it here instead of submitting it as a different answer.

Comment: @xzilla plz post your comment as an answer with an example